# How can I get throughput value for the databases present in the Cosmos DB and their state?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I want to get the details for the database, or I can say, the throughput value for all the databases present in Cosmos DB and also want to check the status if databases are active or not?

Is there any API for the same?If not then, how can I get the throughput and status of databases?

I have been through the documentation of the Cosmos DB, but did not found any help.

`I want to get the throughput value for all the databases present in the Cosmos DB.`

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, as there are different values that you could be referring to: Do you want to know the RU configuration for a collection / database? Or maybe you're asking about the RU cost of specific operations? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: FYI there is documentation that describes how to do all of the above. From an API/SDK standpoint, throughput configurations are described as "offers". And per-operation measurements are retrievable via returned headers. Please show what you've tried and where you're stuck. If it's just a request for a documentation link, unfortunately such a question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the [Python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/find-request-unit-charge#use-the-python-sdk) , you can get it by using the request_charge  ,

> The CosmosClient object from the Python SDK (see this Quickstart
>   regarding its usage) exposes a last_response_headers dictionary that
>   maps all the headers returned by the underlying HTTP API for the last
>   operation executed. The request charge is available under the
>   x-ms-request-charge key.

```
response = client.ReadItem('dbs/database/colls/container/docs/itemId', { 'partitionKey': 'partitionKey' })
request_charge = client.last_response_headers['x-ms-request-charge']
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? Am expecting if there's any API available in Python SDK, which can return me the throughput value for Cosmos DB at the time of deployment.

Comment: You can pass the request as above and get the response

Comment: I tried but its giving error, related to `client` and `ReadItem`.

Comment: @AbhishekKhanna Please edit your question and include your code there. Basically tell us what you have done so far and also include detailed error message you're getting.

Comment: @Sajeetharan - per the OP's comment (which isn't present in the original question, I don't think they're looking for per-operation cost (and fyi there are already a handful of questions & related answers that show precisely how to accomplish that type of operation). The question seems more of a request for documentation, as written.

Answer (score 0):

An example for Python Azure SDK (>=4.0.0)

```
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient

class AzureHelper(object):

    def __init__(self, url, key):
        self.url = url
        self.key = key
        self._client = None
        self._keyspace = None

    def connect(self):
        self._client = CosmosClient(self.url, self.key)

    def get_list_keyspaces(self):
        result = []
        for db in self._client.list_databases():
            result.append(db['id'])
        return result

    def switch_keyspace(self, keyspace):
        self._keyspace = self._client.get_database_client(keyspace)

    def get_list_tables(self):
        result = []
        for table in self._keyspace.list_containers():
            result.append(table['id'])
        return result

    def get_throughput(self, table):
        container = self._keyspace.get_container_client(table)
        offer = container.read_offer()
        throughput = offer.properties['content']['offerThroughput']
        return throughput

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = '<Cosmos DB URL, like https://testdb.cosmos.azure.com:443>'
    key = '<Primary Password>'
    az = AzureHelper(url, key)
    az.connect()
    for keyspace in az.get_list_keyspaces():
        az.switch_keyspace(keyspace)
        for table in az.get_list_tables():
            throughput = az.get_throughput(table)
            print(f'keyspace {keyspace}, table {table}, throughput {throughput}')
```

Comment: please add some more description for better understanding of the solution.